# A basic C Shell for Linux

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have written a basic C Shell. It features the builtins `cd`, `programmer`, `ver` and `exit`. The code for the shell, named `vsh`, is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define TOK_BUFSIZE 64
#define TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a"

char **split_line(char *line)
{
    int bufsize = TOK_BUFSIZE, position = 0;
    char **tokens = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
    char *token, **tokens_backup;

    if (!tokens) {
        fprintf(stderr, "vsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    token = strtok(line, TOK_DELIM);
    while (token != NULL) {
        tokens[position] = token;
        position++;

        if (position >= bufsize) {
            bufsize += TOK_BUFSIZE;
            tokens_backup = tokens;
            tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
            if (!tokens) {
                free(tokens_backup);
                fprintf(stderr, "vsh: allocation error\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, TOK_DELIM);
    }
    tokens[position] = NULL;

    return tokens;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int finish = 0;
    char *user = getenv("USER");
    char hostname[BUFSIZE];
    char *cwd;
    char line[BUFSIZE] = {0};
    char **args;
    char *directory;

    printf("Welcome to vsh\n");

    system("/bin/cat /etc/motd");

    printf("\n");

    gethostname(hostname, BUFSIZE);

    while (!finish)
    {
        cwd = getcwd(cwd, BUFSIZE);

        printf("[");
        printf(user);
        printf("@");
        printf(hostname);
        printf("] ");
        printf(cwd);
        printf(" $ ");
        fflush(stdout);

        if(NULL == fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
        {
            finish = 1;
            printf("\nLeaving vsh\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The command read was %s", line);
            printf("\n");

            args = split_line(line);

            if(strcmp(line, "") == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "vsh: Expected command\n");
            }
            else if(strcmp(args[0], "cd") == 0)
            {
                directory = args[1];
                chdir(directory);
            }
            else if(strcmp(line,"programmer") == 0)
            {
                printf("The programmer of vsh is George Gibson\n");
            }
            else if(strcmp(line,"ver") == 0)
            {
                printf("The current version is 1.0\n");
            }
            else if(strcmp(line,"exit") == 0)
            {
                finish = 1;
                printf("\nLeaving vsh...\n");
                getchar();
            }
            else
            {
                pid_t pid;
                int err;

                pid = fork();

                if(pid == -1) {
                    perror("vsh");
                }
                else if(pid == 0) {
                    execvp(args[0], args);
                    perror("vsh");
                }
                else {
                    waitpid(pid, &err, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm particularly looking for reviews relating to bugs, optimizations and general improvements.

Comment: You don't need to do so many printf calls. You should use the %s more when printing, especially with user input (hostname, username) from the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `main()` function there is a while loop (`while (!finish)`) and in the first few lines of that there are a lot of `printf()` calls. Replace all of those `printf`'s with this one line:

```
printf("[%s@%s] %s $ ", user, hostname, cwd);
```

It is easier to read that way, and with non optimising compilers is slightly more efficient.

Additionally, your `main()` function contains a lot of strings with `vsh` in them. I recommend you replace this:

```
printf("vsh: allocation error\n");
```

with this:

```
printf("%s: allocation error\n", argv[0]);
```

That will make sure that you can more easily change the name of your shell if you want to in the future. In functions other than `main()` the bother of passing `argv[0]` may be more than it is worth, though.

Comment: A single printf with format string isn't just faster or easier to read, the original code with `printf(user)` is a potential security threat. Think of calling `USER="%d" vsh`

Comment: Exactly. With a carefully crafted string one might be able to execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 2):

- You seem to inconsistently use conditional checks:

  - The `!` operator:

    > ```
    > if (!tokens) {
    > ```
  - ["Yoda conditions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions):

    > ```
    > if(NULL == fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
    > ```
  - Not-Yoda conditions:

    > ```
    > if(strcmp(line, "") == 0) {
    > ```

  The second one can still use the `!` operator (in any case with `NULL`), though not the third one because `strcmp()`  returns an `int`.  In any case, you should stick to one style for consistency and where applicable.  It's one's own preference, so choose whichever you prefer.
- This doesn't look too ideal:

  > ```
  > if(NULL == fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
  > {
  >     finish = 1;
  >     printf("\nLeaving vsh\n");
  > }
  > ```

  Consider making the `while` loop infinite by using `1` or `true` instead of `finish`.  At first glance, it may not be clear to the reader that the program should end after this point since there's no `return` or `exit()`.  This will help make it easier for the reader to identify all termination points of the program as opposed to scoping the entire loop flow.
- It may be necessary to terminate the program if either `fork()` or `execvp()` fails.  That is usually more common, but it may still depend on how failure will affect the rest of the program.